# Remove white space from PDF names in a directory using R

Tags: r, loops

I have a directory with some PDFs - and I need to get rid of white space in those titles. So, my first thought was to set the working directly to the appropriate place, and read in the directory:

```
blank <- list()
pdfs <- dir(pattern = "*.pdf")
```

And then loop through the PDFs:

```
for(i in 1:length(pdfs)) {
  gsub(" ", "-", pdfs)
}
```

But this doesn't get it done, and I have a feeling that I'm doing several things incorrectly:

1. I'm not reading the directory correctly
2. The `for` loop is not actually changing anything in the directory itself, but just in the list in R

I would appreciate the correct method! Thanks

Comment: You need to then rename the files, you can use `file.rename()`.

Comment: In any case you don't need a loop. `pdfs_nospace <- gsub(" ", "-", pdfs)`. That doesn't change the file names in the directory though. It is just to show that `gsub` is vectorized.

Comment: If you need to rename them, and you want to rename all at once, `file.rename(from,to)` accepts vectors (same length) for both arguments. That is, you should be able to do `file.rename(pdfs, gsub(" ", "-", pdfs))` without problem. The only inefficiency is that I don't know if it knows to do nothing if there is no change ... but it works nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
# List all file paths ending in .pdf in mydir (not recursively)
fnames <- list.files(mydir, pattern = "\\.pdf$", full.names = TRUE)

# Create the new names replacing spaces to dashes in base names
newnames <- file.path(dirname(fnames), gsub(" ", "-", basename(fnames)))

# If happy with the newnames, rename
file.rename(fnames, newnames)
```

Comment: Worked quite well